# Get data from RowCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowcommand

I have a grid which shows product versions and have a few link buttons like edit, delete, preview etc.
On click of the edit button I want to get the Product ID and Version ID and redirect to some *xyz*.aspx page where the product details can be edited.
Here is how my Grid looks:

```html
<asp:GridView ID="grdBindVersion" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
            onrowcommand="grdBindVersion_RowCommand" >



        <RowStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField datafield="HistoryId"  HeaderText="Version ID.">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

            <asp:BoundField datafield="Title" HeaderText="Title">
                        <HeaderStyle CssClass="grid"></HeaderStyle>
            </asp:BoundField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Edit">
                   <ItemTemplate>

                       <asp:LinkButton ID="Edit" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItem %>'  CommandName ="Add">Edit</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Delete">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="Delete" runat="server">Delete</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Add Sub Page">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="AddSubPage" runat="server">Add Sub Page</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Add Rank">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="AddRank" runat="server">Add Rank</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Approve/DisApprove">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                           <asp:LinkButton ID="ApproveStatus" runat="server">Approve/DisApprove</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Complete">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="Complete" runat="server">Complete</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Preview">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="Preview" runat="server">Preview</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText = "Comment">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:LinkButton ID="Comment" runat="server">Comment</asp:LinkButton>
                   </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>

        </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I am tracking the clicking on the link button  in the `RowCommand` event of the GridView.
Here i want to get the VersionID and ProductID and then redirect to another page.
Please help me.
I am really new to coding.
I did a bit of Google but none of the solutions are helping me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
    {
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
        // row contains current Clicked Gridview Row
        String VersionId = row.Cells[CellIndex].Text;
        .............
        .............
        //e.CommandArgument  -- this return Data Key Value
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can assign more than one assignment to a Gridview's OnRowCommand ...

```
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Feedback Form">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lnkFB" Enabled="true" Text="CREATE"
                        CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ApprenticeshipID") + ";" + Eval("OrganisationID") + ";" + Eval("StudentID") %>' CommandName="btnFB" 
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

And in codebehind, extract the arguments one by one and assign them to session variables for later use ...

```
string[] arg = new string[2]; //say up to 3 arguments (ie: 0,1,2)
arg = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
Session["ApprenticeshipID"] = arg[0]; //I only need first argument
GenerateFeedbackForm(Session["ApprenticeshipID"].ToString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign VersionID and ProductID as DataKeyNames of the GridView and then Pass these two values through Query Strings.

Answer (score -2):

You can get the data on `gridview_RowCommand` event by placing below code:

```
 Int32 HistoryId = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text.ToString());
```

You can set the `[index]` in `Cells[index]` according to your GridView items, then redirect to another page with that fetched HistoryId or ProductId.

Comment: Hi Saurabh. I tried your code but it is giving an error.

System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' does not contain a definition for 'Row' and no extension method 'Row' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCommandEventArgs' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Set the CommandArgument='<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "HistoryId")%>' to the edit button and use below code: 
if (e.CommandName.Equals("Add"))
        {

            
            int HistoryId = Convert.ToInt16(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
            // Redirect

        }

Comment: This answer is invalid, although the comment is correct, yet conflicts completely with the actual answer. I think some editing is in order